# NZXT – ASUS M5A97 R2.0 and 18.04.1 Installation Problems

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, asus

Need some help from the community to get my new system going.  (Actually not-so-new: bought the parts a while back – 18.04 will be out so waited, issues, read suggestions to wait for 18.04.1, still issues, read motherboard problems so bought a new motherboard which works per a post and usable with my CPU.  Obviously still issues as I’m posting.)

The (current) System:

- Motherboard: ASUS M5A97 R2.0 AMD 970
- CPU:         AMD FX-8320 Eight-Core
- Memory:      32 GB
- PSU:         EV3A  750 W  (reasonably certain)
- Video    Card:       XFX R7-250E-ZNP4
- Case is by NZXT – ah-ha! That’s where that    came from in the
  Subject!  Just trying to             come up with a unique    subject so I
  could find my thread and yet others find the
              motherboard in their search for assistance.
- ISO Used:      ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-md64.iso   Did not do a checksum (how??) Did do the disk check option on the DVD – both the RW and R burns.
- BluRay R/W (can’t find the specs)
- Crucial SSD card 275 GB  Intended    for the Boot and some data
  storage
- Western Digital  HDD 3    TB Intended for ‘active’ data.

The problem:
All the installs have failed to varying degrees.  Some barely get off the ground (from my notes): “ Locked up at [7] fb: switching to amdgpudrmfb from EFI VGA”.  Sometimes further in: “[87]  kernel panic – not syncing: Attempted to kill init! Exitcode=0x0000000b”.  Have gotten to the Bionic Beaver Desktop (hooray!!) and started the installation.  Usually get two or three “System Problem Detected” errors which I send in (I’m probably on the troubleshooters blacklist by now! – Joke!!)

Have tried various installation options/commands:  del “quiet splash”, replace with ‘nomodeset’, ‘radeon.nodeset=0’, ‘fb=false’ and a few others (without the quotes, of course) – the three hyphens at the end of the line are left in.

The ‘try’ option doesn’t seem to be able to get to the Bionic Beaver Desktop nearly as often as the ‘Install’ option.  Strange thing about the Install option is I’ll see “Failed to start Ubuntu live CD installer” in the text (when I’m paying attention), which probably explains why if I get to the Desktop I usually see the “Install Ubuntu” icon on the Desktop (so yes, sometimes just appears in the Launcher).

I have attempted to look up other users’ threads and scanned through the Ubuntu 18.04 Installation Manual (AMD version).  Must be missing something which hopefully you folks can point out.   Sorry about the length: trying to give as much troubleshooting information as possible.

TIA!
Barry

Comment: FWIW tried replacing "quiet splash" with "fb=false  service rsyslog stop".  Got partway through the installation process but "ubi-partman failed with exit code 10."  Bug report posted as  1815151 .

Comment: Me again! Appears the problem was 'multifold'. (1) "Bad" RAM, but only found when used the memory test utility configured for cycling through all the CPU cores.  (2)  BIOS needed updating to be compatible with the CPU I was using.  (2a) The updated firmware allowed my to set CSM to install Ubuntu 18.04.2.   ...Finally!!